# Regarding asmx Webservice issue

Tags: xml, web-services, serialization, asmx, invalidoperationexception

I have an asmx webservice that receives the XML files from the client and store it into my developed application in the respective server. The process is successful and I am able to see the response files sent by the client.

But, the Client reports that they see the following error in their logs and unable to see the return message from our server.

```
Serialization Error:  ---> System.InvalidOperationException: There is an error in XML document (1, 1). ---> System.Xml.XmlException: Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseRootLevelWhitespace()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent()
   at System.Xml.XmlReader.MoveToContent()
   at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderStatusList.Read5_StatusList()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, Str
```

Could someone please help me on how to fix this? I couldn't figure out the root cause of this?